# Tax Rounding Issue in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hey guys thanks in advance if you can answer this question!

In Woocommerce if for example we have a product that costs lets say $15.95 and delivery is $7.50 that makes a subtotal of $23.45. The tax rate in our province is 5%. If we take the subtotal of $23.45 and multiply that by 1.05 to get the new total with tax it comes to $24.6225.

The total is of course rounded to two decimal places but for some reason it is rounding this UP to $24.63 instead of down to $24.62.

Is this an American thing or something?
Shouldn't third decimal less than 5 be rounded down?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a result of them calculating and rounding tax for each item separately.

15.96 * 1.05 = 16.7475

7.50 * 1.05 = 7.875

If we round these before we add them together we get 16.75 + 7.88 = 24.63

Comment: Ahhhh I see, so Woocommerce calculates and rounds tax for each thing individually? I figured it just took item (total item price + shipping) x tax. What you are saying now makes sense.

Is there a way to change the way everything is calculated in Woocommerce?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm using a 3rd party software that syncs inventory and orders between website and POS system. For some reason this 3rd party software recalculates the order total when sending it to POS and if there is any discrepency like $0.01 it gets stuck in infinite loop sending order millions of times.

Comment: I haven't used Woocommerce but I found this you could try https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/#section-6